# Usage of the word later

Tags: time

Mohan started writing a story on 3oth May and finishes it 2 days later. When did he finish it?

Is the answer 1st June or 2nd June? Please explain. Thanks

Comment: Exam Qs. may be off topic on ELU. In any case, this is too elementary for ELU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st June. A simple way to understand it would be to count the days:

0 days later would be 30th May.
1 day later would be 31st May.
2 days later is 1st June.
3 days later is 2nd June.